# PostgreSQL and Single Table Inheritance

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I read about STI (Single Table Inheritance) and like the idea.

Does PostgreSQL handle 95% NULL values in some columns if I have about 1M rows well?

Does it impact performance if there many columns (~70) and many of them contain mostly NULL values?

Infos about STI:

- SQLAlchemy http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=single%20table%20inheritance#single-table-inheritance
- http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html

PS: unfortunately there is not tag for "STI" in this StackExchange site yer

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229805/how-much-disk-space-is-needed-to-store-a-null-value-using-postgresql-db

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan thank you for this link. I understand it like this: PostgreSQL needs one bit for every nullable column. That is not much.